# MySQL - select customers which made at least x orders in the last y days and have not order for the last z days

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get customers which made at least `x` orders in the last `y` days and have not made an order in the last `z` days, so my client could know which customers are "leaving" and not coming back.

my table is very simple:

### Orders

```
- ID
- Created (UNIX timestamp)
- CustomerID
```

### Customers

```
- ID
- Name
- Phone
```

I succeeded to select `x` orders in the last `y` days, but I could not join the data so i will get only the customers which haven't order for the last `z` days

this is my query for customers which made more than 1 order in the last 30 days:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(t1.CustomerID) as customer_count,
    t2.ID as customer_id,
    t2.Name,
    t2.Phone
FROM
    Orders t1
JOIN
    Customers t2
        ON t1.CustomerID = t2.ID
WHERE
    t1.Created BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (86400*30)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY
    t2.ID
HAVING customer_count >= 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you succeeded the in first part and the second part is mainly the same, you can make it easy by copying the query, make the minor modifications, and add it as a subquery to the `HAVING` condition. Try this for customers who didn't make any order in the last 7 days:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(o1.CustomerID) as customer_count,
    c1.ID as customer_id,
    c1.Name,
    c1.Phone
FROM Customers c1
LEFT JOIN Orders o1 ON o1.CustomerID = c1.ID
WHERE o1.Created BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (86400*30)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY c1.ID
HAVING customer_count > 1
   AND (SELECT 
            COUNT(o2.CustomerID) as customer_count,
        FROM Customers c2
        LEFT JOIN Orders o2 ON o2.CustomerID = c2.ID
        WHERE o2.Created BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (86400*7)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
          AND c2.ID = c1.ID
        GROUP BY c2.ID) = 0
```

Notes:

- I changed your condition from `customer_count >= 2` to `customer_count > 1`
   as it reads better.
- I recommend starting with main table `Customers` and then join `Orders` because it feels more natural.
- I also recommend using more meaningful aliases that `t1` and `t2`. For instance, `c` and `o` read much better. With the query above, you can do something like `c1`, `c2`, `o1`, and `o2`.

**EDIT** Since the subquery is counting orders for only one given customer, we don't need the grouping so We can simplify it like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(o.CustomerID) as customer_count,
    c.ID as customer_id,
    c.Name,
    c.Phone
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.CustomerID = c.ID
WHERE o.Created BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (86400*30)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY c.ID
HAVING customer_count > 1
   AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Orders o2
        WHERE o2.Created BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (86400*7)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
          AND o2.CustomerID = c.ID) = 0
```

Comment: thank you, i was able to run your query but i didnt get the right result, today i didnt have any order so i tried to change the `7` to `1` so it will show my the customers which made an order in the last 30 days and have not order in the last 1 day and i didnt get any result

Comment: i think that your query is showing me the customers which made an order in the last `y` days and also make an order in the last `z` days

Comment: In the second query, we need to `LEFT JOIN` on the orders otherwise we won't get a count. Try the updated answer.

Comment: still not getting any result, current me if I wrong but I should get all the customers if I change `7` days to `1` day? I'm getting empty results

Comment: Copy the subquery, remove the condition `AND c2.ID = c1.ID`, and run it. What do you get? The count of all your customers?

Comment: it returns 1 row with the value 1 - just a few minutes ago a new order was submitted

Comment: Yeah, so it is working as it should. Now try the whole query again. What do you get?

Comment: I'm getting 0 rows

Comment: See my updated answer. Try the simplified version, it should perform better too.